# How to migrate to etherium mainnet without paying for gas

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development

I'm creating a dapp. I already deployed my contracts to ropsten testnet, but now I'm looking to deploy them to mainnet without paying a gas fee for deployment. If what I'm asking for is not possible, then I would instead like to find out how to estimate the minimum gas fee I would have to pay to deploy my contracts to mainnet via truffle.

Answer (score 0):

You cant deploy a contract without paying for gas no matter what. And the gas fee you're going to pay depends on how big your code is

Comment: How much gas fee need ......just idea...

Comment: It depends on your contract